# High CPU usage on mongodb server when idle?

Tags: mongodb

I'm getting strange usage numbers on MongoDB server when it is in almost idle state: http://pastebin.com/cKVyGMts (no queries) DB size is about 3.3 Gb.

I can see in `mongodb.log` that snapshotthread is eating too much CPU:

> Wed Nov 28 19:02:14 [snapshotthread] cpu: elapsed:4000  writelock: 0%
>   Wed Nov 28 19:02:18 [snapshotthread] cpu: elapsed:4000  writelock: 0%
>   Wed Nov 28 19:02:22 [snapshotthread] cpu: elapsed:4000  writelock: 0%
>   Wed Nov 28 19:02:26 [snapshotthread] cpu: elapsed:4000  writelock: 0%

And data from top confirms it: http://pastebin.com/d57ybpBJ (iotop shows that there are no high disk activity present).

I'm running high-cpu instance on EC2, mongo confing and startup information is here: http://pastebin.com/YZyyq0gc.

How I can disable snapshotting or what can cause such a high CPU usage?

Comment: Whet version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: db version v2.0.8 from 10gen repo Centos 6.2

Comment: did you try turning off snapshotting?  cpu = false or just comment out cpu=true.  Also check this bug out: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2114

Comment: Thanks, turning off snaphotting didnt cause any effect. I've straced mongo and found that log is filled with select and setsockopts: select(10, [8 9], NULL, NULL, {0, 10000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(10, [8 9], NULL, NULL, {0, 10000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(10, [8 9], NULL, NULL, {0, 10000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(10, [8 9], NULL, NULL, {0, 10000}) = 0 (Timeout)

Comment: How is "Cpu(s):  3.0%us,  1.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 95.5%id,  0.3%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st" high load? That's 95+% idle.

Answer (score 1):

According to JIRA some changes where made to memory allocation algorithm in version 2.2.0, which possibly could fix this issue.

[MongoDB high CPU usage, low disk IO, very slow response](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5401)

Comment: thank you for the answer!! unfortunately, this didn't work ;/ upgraded to db version v2.2.2, pdfile version 4.5 git version: d1b43b61a5308c4ad0679d34b262c5af9d664267

Comment: ok, did you try to disable NUMA? http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/NUMA

Comment: restarted server with command: numactl --interleave=all /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (cat /proc/sys/vm/zone_reclaim_mode
0 - no luck;/

Comment: ok, try to increase syncdelay: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod--syncdelay

Comment: no luck;/ i now think the problem is more OS specific http://pastebin.com/yaGL4cYm because i have 8 cores and mongod CPU usage is 2200% (!!!??) i'll try to update CentOS to the lastest version.

Comment: Any useful feedback on the subject would be great. Did you find the root cause of the problem?

Comment: You are misreading the output. You'll notice that only one core is spending significant time in user space (18.2%) and the others are almost completely idle (over 95% idle). You only have 8 cores, so clearly that 2200% can't be CPU usage.